# Installing Bosh Lite on Windows 10

Tags: windows, local, cloud-foundry, bosh-deployer, cf-bosh

I tried following this guide to install bosh lite on my windows 10 machine:
https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite

If I download the bosh-cli-2.0.28-windows-amd64.exe and open it, it just opens up a command prompt and it immediately closes it.

The second problem is, that all console commands are for linux/ubuntu.

What I´m doing wrong? Is it possible to get bosh light 2 running on a windows machine.

I have to say, I´m a newbie to this stuff, so is this a task that can be done or whould I have to use linux?

Greetings
Marcel

Update: Ok, I understand now that it must installed over the console. But the complete tutorial including console comands is for linux. Does somebody know a tutorial for windows or how to translate the linux commands in windows? The tutorial: bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite

Comment: Have you considered using the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: No, in the end I used the Pivotal PCF Dev software, which makes it really easy to run a lightweight cloud foundry instance on your local windows machine :).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Install VirtualBox on Windows
2. Install Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux ( WSL )
3. Install bosh cli in WSL
4. Trick bosh cli in WSL to use virtualbox which is in Windows ( assuming default location for VBoxManage.exe )

```
sudo ln -s "/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe" /usr/local/bin/vboxmanage
```

5. Provide shared storage that works for both vboxmanage in windows AND bosh cli in WSL

```
mkdir -p /mnt/c$HOME/.bosh_virtualbox_cpi
ln -s /mnt/c$HOME/.bosh_virtualbox_cpi $HOME/.bosh_virtualbox_cpi
```

6. Go a ahead and follow the remaining instructions for using bosh cli to create a bosh-lite installation, do this from WSL, the "bosh create-env ..." will work.

The steps are further explained in [Yes — You can run BOSH Lite v2 on Windows 10!](https://medium.com/@philippe.khalife/yes-you-can-run-bosh-lite-v2-on-windows-10-b55f679640b9)